# Nginx + Unicorn Configuration Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-web-services, unicorn

I am in the proces of migrating from Passenger to Unicorn and I am having a bit of trouble getting the configuration working.

The issue that I am seeing is that all of my connections seem to time out, but there are no errors logged in the stderr.log and stdout.log files. I have verified that my ports are open on the AWS sec group.

This is what I am seeing in my stderr.log

```
I, [2012-08-21T19:26:36.462776 #7989]  INFO -- : unlinking existing socket=/data/test/staging/current/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock
I, [2012-08-21T19:26:36.463048 #7989]  INFO -- : listening on addr=/data/test/staging/current/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock fd=3
I, [2012-08-21T19:26:36.463466 #7989]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2012-08-21T19:27:50.293399 #7989]  INFO -- : master process ready
I, [2012-08-21T19:27:50.687491 #8083]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
I, [2012-08-21T19:27:50.751790 #8086]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
cache: [GET /] miss
```

Here is my current configuration structure:

**nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  2;
daemon off;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log;

  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;

  keepalive_timeout  65;

  gzip  on;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_comp_level 2;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript application/json;

  server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**unicorn.rb**

```
worker_processes 2
working_directory "/data/test/staging/current"

preload_app true

timeout 30
listen "/data/test/staging/current/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock", :backlog => 64

pid "/data/test/staging/current/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"

# Set the path of the log files inside the log folder of the testapp
stderr_path "/data/test/staging/current/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path "/data/test/staging/current/log/unicorn.stdout.log"

before_fork do |server, worker|
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

**000-default**

```
upstream test_server {
 #This is the socket we configured in unicorn.rb
 server unix:/data/test/staging/current/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock »
 fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
listen 80;
client_max_body_size 4G;
server_name http://ec2-23-22-53-139.compute-1.amazonaws.com;

keepalive_timeout 5;

# Location of our static files
root /data/test/staging/current/public;

location / {
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_redirect off;

  # If you don't find the filename in the static files
  # Then request it from the unicorn server
  if (!-f $request_filename) {
    proxy_pass http://test_server;
    break;
  }
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
location = /500.html {
  root /data/test/staging/current/public;
}
}
```

Comment: Might want to check and post your nginx access and error logs, and maybe set up a separate one in your test server block to see if it's being activated.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by putting the Socket and Pid files in the shared directory. EG,

```
/data/test/staging/shared/sockets
/data/test/staging/shared/pids
```

This will help when the application is deployed and the "current folder" changed to the next release (assuming you are deployin with capistrano).

Comment: Thanks! Using rails_app/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock instead of /tmp/unicorn.sock fixed for me!